# Returning two pieces of data from a tables based on a two different joins

Tags: sql

I'm sure there is an answer out there for this, I am just having a hard time explaining what exactly it is I am looking for making it really hard to research:

I basically have 2 tables:

Table A:

```
PrimaryKeyID
SalesmanID
ManagerID
```

Table B:

```
List of all employers with ID being the primary key (auto incremented from 1)
```

I need to get both the Salesman and Manager Names from Table B, from a specific row in table A.  Consider Table A like a transaction log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a way to do it

```
SELECT A.ID, SalesMan.NAME, Manager.NAME
FROM TableA A
LEFT JOIN TableB SalesMan ON SalesMan.Id= A.SalesmanID 
LEFT JOIN TableB Manager ON Manager.Id= A.ManagerID 
WHERE (A.Your condition here)
    AND  (SalesMan.SalesmanID IS NOT NULL OR Manager.ManagerID IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Oh, that makes sense now why you can "name" your Joins differently, thank you!